# In Pyramid, how can I read from a file on the end user's machine (no need to save it)?

Tags: python, csv, file-upload, pyramid

I am writing a bit of code that will take a CSV file input and perform an operation based on its contents. In the admin panel I am designing, the admin should be able to select a CSV file on their local system which my application will then read. The application does not need to store the CSV file, just read from it for a one-time operation.

Any ideas on how to best handle this in Pyramid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is essentially a file upload, followed by additional processing on the uploaded data. You can create `input` elements of type `"file"` in HTML forms to allow uploading of files.

Refer to the [cookbook in the Pyramid documentation on file uploads](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/forms/file_uploads.html) for how to handle the uploaded data on the server side (summarized: use the file-like object `request.POST[ field_name ].file`).

Comment: Good answer. Also note that it is not possible to access the file system from the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Should be all set now. :)